# Is there an efficient way to backward search a large vector in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, lookup

I have a vector of 10+ million elements. 
I need to find all elements satisfying a given condition A (e.g. X < 2 at rows `i %in% c(6,10)`). 
From each of these elements I need to skim the vector backwards and flag all preceding elements while they satisfy condition B (e.g. X < 4 for `i %in% c(8:10) and c(5:6)`).

For example, given the following X column, I would like the final result to be the `flag2` column. I am not interested in elements where B is true if they are not immediately preceding an element satisfying A, therefore row `i == 2` has `flag2 == 0`.

```r
  i  |  X  | flag1 | flag2
---------------------------
  1  |  4  |   0   |   0
  2  |  3  |   0   |   0
  3  |  6  |   0   |   0
  4  |  9  |   0   |   0
  5  |  3  |   0   |   1
  6  |  1  |   1   |   1
  7  |  9  |   0   |   0
  8  |  3  |   0   |   1
  9  |  2  |   0   |   1
 10  |  1  |   1   |   1
```

The first operation to produce flag1 is simple and very fast:

```r
# locate all occurrences of X < 2
my_data$flag1 = dplyr::case_when(my_data$X < 2 ~ 1, T ~ 0)
```

I have implemented the second operation with the following for loop, which gives the desired result but is prohibitively time-consuming given the amount of data.

```r
# flag all elements preceding the ones already flagged while they satisfy `X < 4`
my_data$flag2 = my_data$flag1
for(i in nrow(my_data):2){
  if((my_data[i,]$flag2 == 1) & (my_data[i-1,]$X < 4)){ 
    my_data[i-1,]$flag2 = 1
  }
}
```

Is there any way I could do this more efficiently?

Comment: @Cettt I have edited the question adding toy data and also better describing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following can seed it up.
It is `subsetting` and shifting the index of `flag` by one position like and repeating it until it does not flag anymore:

```
my_data  <- data.frame(X=c(4,3,6,9,3,1,9,3,2,1))

my_data$flag1 <- my_data$X < 2
my_data$flag2 <-  my_data$flag1
repeat {
  tt <- my_data$X < 4 & c(my_data$flag2[-1], FALSE)
  if(all(!(tt & !my_data$flag2))) break
  my_data$flag2[tt]  <- TRUE
}
my_data
   X flag1 flag2
1  4 FALSE FALSE
2  3 FALSE FALSE
3  6 FALSE FALSE
4  9 FALSE FALSE
5  3 FALSE  TRUE
6  1  TRUE  TRUE
7  9 FALSE FALSE
8  3 FALSE  TRUE
9  2 FALSE  TRUE
10 1  TRUE  TRUE
```

or using `Reduce`:

```
my_data  <- data.frame(X=c(4,3,6,9,3,1,9,3,2,1))

my_data$flag1 <- my_data$X < 2
my_data  <- my_data[nrow(my_data):1,]
fun <- function(x, y) {c(y[[1]] || (x[[1]] && y[[2]]), FALSE)}
my_data$flag2  <- do.call(rbind, Reduce(fun
  , as.data.frame(rbind(my_data$flag1, my_data$X < 4))[,-1]
  , c(my_data$flag1[1], FALSE), accumulate = TRUE))[,1]
my_data  <- my_data[nrow(my_data):1,]
my_data
#   X flag1 flag2
#1  4 FALSE FALSE
#2  3 FALSE FALSE
#3  6 FALSE FALSE
#4  9 FALSE FALSE
#5  3 FALSE  TRUE
#6  1  TRUE  TRUE
#7  9 FALSE FALSE
#8  3 FALSE  TRUE
#9  2 FALSE  TRUE
#10 1  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another possibility using the `accumulate` function from the `purrr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data  <- data.frame(X=c(4,3,6,9,3,1,9,3,2,1))

my_fun <- function(flag1, xlag) if ((flag1 == 1 & xlag < 4) | xlag < 2) 1 else 0

my_data %>%
  mutate(flag1 = if_else(X < 2, 1, 0),
         flag2 = rev(accumulate(rev(X), my_fun, .init = last(flag1))[-1]))

   X flag1 flag2
1  4     0     0
2  3     0     0
3  6     0     0
4  9     0     0
5  3     0     1
6  1     1     1
7  9     0     0
8  3     0     1
9  2     0     1
10 1     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using the `data.table` package, then it takes less than 1s for 10million rows using:

```
library(data.table)
nr <- 10e6
set.seed(0L)
my_data <- data.frame(X=sample(1:9, nr, TRUE))

system.time({
    setDT(my_data)[, flag2 := { 
        flag1 <- X < 2
        b <- rleid(X < 4)
        +(b %in% b[flag1])
    }]
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.30    0.12    0.42
```

output:

```
          X flag2
       1: 9     0
       2: 4     0
       3: 7     0
       4: 1     1
       5: 2     1
      ---        
 9999996: 6     0
 9999997: 1     1
 9999998: 9     0
 9999999: 6     0
10000000: 1     1
```

`head(my_data, 10)`:

```
    X flag2
 1: 9     0
 2: 4     0
 3: 7     0
 4: 1     1
 5: 2     1
 6: 7     0
 7: 2     1
 8: 3     1
 9: 1     1
10: 5     0
```